# Removing timestamp from a file using php

Tags: php, json, timestamp

I need to remove a timestamp  `[04-Nov-2014 12:22:17 UTC]` from an `error_log` using php. The timestamps occur at the beginning and EOF and the file does not have any line breaks.
The `error_log` looks somewhat like this. Its in JSON format.

```
[04-Nov-2014 12:22:17 UTC]{"buyer_accepts_marketing":false,"cart_token":"eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c","closed_at":null,"completed_at":null,"created_at":null,"currency":null,"email":"","gateway":null,"id":327474488104976385,"landing_site":null,"note":null,"referring_site":null,"shipping_lines":
```

I have tried `preg_match()`, `array_shift()` etc. But none of it provided a satisfiable output.

What is the best way to do this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this `pre_replace();`:

```
$string =   '[04-Nov-2014 12:22:17 UTC]{"buyer_accepts_marketing":false,"cart_token":"eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c","closed_at":null,"completed_at":null,"created_at":null,"currency":null,"email":"","gateway":null,"id":327474488104976385,"landing_site":null,"note":null,"referring_site":null,"shipping_lines":';

echo preg_replace('/\[([0-9\-a-zA-Z]{1,}) ([0-9\:]{1,}) ([0-9\a-zA-Z]{1,})\]/',"",$string);
```

Comment: That didnt work. Maybe theres something wrong with the regex. Let me take another look at it. I am not vry familiar with regexs.

Comment: Sry mistake at my end. Tkz for the quick rply Rasclatt.